# AFNetworking Upload Image Error

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to upload an image to a server, but I'm running into a problem. Here's the code that I have:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profileImage.png"];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"http://myserver.com/upload_img.php?&user_id=6&image=image.png" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
}

    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
}

      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I'm getting "Success: {error = "";}" from NSLog, but the server is not updating. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Ok, the image is uploading correctly, but we had to use GET instead of POST on the server for retrieving the image. Why would this be?

Comment: I guess you need to debug the server to figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profileImage.png"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"http://myserver.com/upload_img.php?&user_id=6&image=image.png" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){

    }
     {
          [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! With a POST call, I needed to set the correct parameters: `@{user_id:@6}`. Working great now!